# insert into datatable or update if it exist

Tags: c#, ms-access, upsert

I am trying to update and insert 1 data table to another. If the work order in the data table(c2 barcode) is the same it will update the data table(c1 barcode)and if it is not the same it will insert into data table c1 barcode from data table c2 barcode. I am able to run the code and for the inserting part it inserts into the database correctly but for the updating part, it does not work. Is there a mistake in my update or conditions?

```cs
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand checkrecord = new OleDbCommand("SELECT workorder FROM [c1 barcode]", connection);
OleDbCommand checkrecord2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT workorder FROM [c2 barcode]", connection);
if (checkrecord == checkrecord2)
{
    string query = "UPDATE [c1 barcode], [c2 barcode] SET [c1 barcode].[Close from care] = [c2 barcode].[close from care], [c1 barcode].[Name care] = [c2 barcode].[name care] WHERE ([c1 barcode].Workorder=[c2 barcode].[workorder]);";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("updated");
    }
}
else if (checkrecord != checkrecord2)
{
    string query2 = "INSERT INTO [c1 barcode] SELECT [c2 barcode].* FROM [c2 barcode]";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("inserted");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Maybe ```checkrecord ``` is not equal to  ```checkrecord2 ``` a white space could do that check your returning data thats why probably the update query never executed

Comment: I debugged and check it. It does get data from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to run a check first.  It will work if you simply run two SQL statements, like this:

```
connection.Open();
string updateQuery = "UPDATE [c1 barcode], [c2 barcode] SET [c1 barcode].[Close from care] = [c2 barcode].[close from care], [c1 barcode].[Name care] = [c2 barcode].[name care] WHERE ([c1 barcode].Workorder=[c2 barcode].[workorder]);";
string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO [c1 barcode] SELECT * FROM [c2 barcode] c2 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [c1 barcode] WHERE Workorder = c2.Workorder)";
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(updateQuery, connection))
{
    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("updated");
    }
}
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insertQuery, connection))
{
    if ((int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("inserted");
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

This assumes that Workorder is a primary key, which I presumed is correct because of your insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

`checkrecord == checkrecord2` is wrong, you are just comparing two `OleDbCommand` objects, I guess you have two execute those two commands and then compare the output of those commands

something like this:

```
//psuedo code
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand cmd_checkrecord = new OleDbCommand("SELECT workorder FROM [c1 barcode]", connection);
OleDbCommand cmd_checkrecord2 = new OleDbCommand("SELECT workorder FROM [c2 barcode]", connection);
var checkrecord = Convert.ToString(cmd_checkrecord.ExecuteScalar());
var checkrecord2 = Convert.ToString(cmd_checkrecord2.ExecuteScalar());

if (checkrecord == checkrecord2)
{
    string query = "UPDATE [c1 barcode], [c2 barcode] SET [c1 barcode].[Close from care] = [c2 barcode].[close from care], [c1 barcode].[Name care] = [c2 barcode].[name care] WHERE ([c1 barcode].Workorder=[c2 barcode].[workorder]);";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection))
    {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        MessageBox.Show("updated");
    }
}
else if (checkrecord != checkrecord2)
{
    string query2 = "INSERT INTO [c1 barcode] SELECT [c2 barcode].* FROM [c2 barcode]";
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query2, connection))
    {

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("inserted");
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("error");
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: hmm it still does insert only and does not update the records.

Comment: have some courtesy to check the value of `checkrecord` and `checkrecord2`, it seems it is never equal after command execution

Comment: maybe you can convert the returned values to string and then check for equality, check updated post

Comment: When i added ORDER BY workorder in the select query it does the update and not the insert. Is this caused by the if else ?